# Add member to list of channels in slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Is there a way to add a user/member to a list of a hundred or more (existing) slack channels automatically? *Perhaps a slack bot, however, I am unable to find any examples of this that don't require listening for new channel creation events.*

Comment: any solution? even via API you can't do that since the bot is not int channels. that's strange tbh.

Answer (score 3):

I found using the /invite command saves quite a few clicks. I copied the below command and then I could paste it into each channel and press enter -> done.

For open channels its instant. For locked channels you need a click to do final grant.
Still this was much faster than before

/invite @johndoe

Answer (score 2):

Every few weeks I need to add a few people to an assortment of channels. Surely the folks at Slack could add a UI screen to allow one to specify the person or persons and then check all the channels that they should be added to.

It's soooooo time consuming to add them now!

Answer (score 0):

Found a No script, no extensions solution:

1. Type the **/who** command on a channel you want to add.
2. Copy the output
3. Paste it in the channel where you want those people to get invited to
4. Press **Intro/Enter** key
   Slack will ask all those people "that are not in the channel yet". Press the Invite button you'll get list of members invited.

Comment: I have 300 or so existing slack channels, i need to add a couple existing users to all of those channels fast.